In a docker-compose set up Is it possible to communicate with backend container in azure app service using a react front end container?
I am trying to host a multi-container web app on azure web app for containers. I have a docker-compose file with the front end and backend images and locally it works fine but on azure my axios post request doesn't succeed. I understand azure only exposes port:80 publicly but can the front end hit the flask API in any way since they're both on the same app service.
I have tried docker service name with and without the port number in the url and it doesn't resolve due to either the front end being hosted on https and trying a http request or the url does not resolve when I use https.
    const backendUrl = "https:backend:5000/api/upload"; // i have tried multiple other urls

    try {
      onUploadStart();
      const response = await axios.post(backendUrl, formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
      onUploadSuccess(response);
    } catch (error) {
      onUploadError("Error uploading file. Please try again.");
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

I was expecting this request to be able to hit the backend container but it looks like the post request is always executed from the client's browser and azure is only exposing the frontend so it always fails, my question is is there any way to get around that for the 2 containers to be able to communicate internally?
so just to recap I have a docker-compose.yml


services:
  frontend:
    image: somefrontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    image: somebackend  
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - GEMINI_API_KEY= somekey 

hosted on azure web app (app service + app service plan) and i want to know if there is a way for the frontend to hit the backend with a post request if the backend is not exposed publicly?

have you tried with docker network ?

Yes, it is possible to establish communication between a React frontend container and a backend container, both hosted in Azure App Service using Docker Compose.
I followed this link to set up a multi-container application using docker-compose.yml.
Below is an example of the docker-compose.yml file:
Use docker-compose.yml as below
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend



Change your react app code with backend url i.e:http://localhost:5000/upload
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FileUpload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (!file) {
      setMessage('Please select a file first!');
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });
      setMessage(response.data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage('File upload failed.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;



In your Flask app, add CORS code to allow CORS from all domains by adding the following code:
 from flask_cors import CORS

CORS(app)


Output:


Hello Naveen, thanks for your reply but I don't think works in production on azure for 2 reasons 1) the front end is hosted on https so it doesn't allow http requests and 2) this post request is executed from the client's browser and azure doesn't expose the backend publicly so the request doesn't resolve. It works on docker locally because the client request is executed from the same machine running the backend service
